# Modern Document Library search not working for nested folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-search, modern-document-library

I am able get results when I am searching in the root folder of the library, but when I try to search inside a folder in the same library, the search does not work as expected. (In Modern UI of SharePoint online document library)

for example-
If I types a keyword in the search box in the top left-hand corner, then clicks "see more results", get the message "no items match your search".
how ever matching documents already there in library inside folder.

Library has exceeded threshold limit. having around 70K files.

Answer (score 0):

In my SharePoint online site, it could work well.

Could you search files within other folders at the same library? and check if search within the folder could work in classic mode.

After you upload files into the folder, you need to wait some hours for crawling. So, please wait some hours, then search again.